# Exploiting Monotonicity in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I have a large Numpy array and I want to apply some function elementwise if element is positive and replace with -inf otherwise. The array is basically an outer difference of two vectors (see the example if not clear), and therefore it has a particular structure: each row starts from positive numbers and at some point becomes negative, for instance, when I subtract [1,...,10] from [3,4,5] I get the matrix

```
2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 ...
3  2  1  0 -1 -2 ...
4  3  2  1  0 -1 ...
```

(of course, in the real application the vectors are not evenly space integers)

and I want to get

```
f(2)  f(1)  f(0)  -inf -inf -inf ...
f(3)  f(2)  f(1)  f(0) -inf -inf ...
f(4)  f(3)  f(2)  f(1) f(0) -inf ...
```

There is a straightforward solution:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(2000,dtype=np.float64)
y = np.arange(4000,dtype=np.float64)

M = x[:,None] - y[None,:]

i_pos = M>=0

M[i_pos] = np.sqrt(M[i_pos])
M[~i_pos] = -np.inf
```

It works but seems pretty inefficient as looking for positive elements does not account for the monotonicity (if traveling along a row we encountered negative number we should not go further).

More general example

```
x = np.arange(10000,dtype=np.float64).reshape(100,100)
y = np.arange(4000,dtype=np.float64)

M = x[:,:,None] - y[None,None,:]

i_pos = M>0

M[i_pos] = np.sqrt(M[i_pos])
M[~i_pos] = -np.inf
```

takes more than one second.

Is there a way to reasonably exploit this structure to get some speed improvement? I tried to work out a Numba function with a loop, however it did not seem to be much faster (1.38 sec vs 1.18 sec + compilation time).

Comment: That masking takes some part of runtime too. Have you tried with `np.where` : `np.where(i_pos,np.sqrt(M),-np.inf)`? Also, if you are dealing with large arrays, look into `numexpr` as it also has sqrt implementation.

Comment: np.where seems to be of the same speed and also, if I understand correctly, it computes the whole np.sqrt(M) (which also produces a warning as some elements are negative and may not work well with a custom function). Have not looked at numexpr yet, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Memory allocations are the limiting part

If you use functions like sqrt, exp, sin, cos make sure you have installed [Intel SVML](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html). Also add all things you tried so far and how you got your timings.

Your Numpy solution uses temporary arrays, so there should be quite some room for improvement.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def calc_M(x,y):
    M = x[:,:,None] - y[None,None,:]

    i_pos = M>0

    M[i_pos] = np.sqrt(M[i_pos])
    M[~i_pos] = -np.inf
    return M

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def calc_M_nb_1(x,y):
    res=np.empty((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],y.shape[0]))
    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            for k in range(y.shape[0]):
                val= x[i,j]-y[k]
                if val>0:
                    res[i,j,k]=np.sqrt(val)
                else:
                    res[i,j,k]=-np.inf
    return res

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def calc_M_nb_2(x,y,res):
    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            for k in range(y.shape[0]):
                val= x[i,j]-y[k]
                if val>0:
                    res[i,j,k]=np.sqrt(val)
                else:
                    res[i,j,k]=-np.inf
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
x = np.arange(10000,dtype=np.float64).reshape(100,100)
y = np.arange(4000,dtype=np.float64)
res=np.empty((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],y.shape[0]))

%timeit res_1=calc_M(x,y)
469 ms ± 3.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=calc_M_nb_1(x,y)
79.5 ms ± 671 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
res=np.empty((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],y.shape[0]))
%timeit res_3=calc_M_nb_2(x,y,out)
25.5 ms ± 204 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If you compare the timings of `calc_M_nb_2` and  `calc_M_nb_1` it can be seen, that the memory allocation takes more time than the whole calculations which is not a rare case in simple functions.
Of course it is not always possible to avoid memory allocations, but if you want to apply this functions to a lot of similar inputs (array size), you can get quite some speedup.